# How do I create an array dynamically?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create an array like this by code.

```
let arr = {
    'First': {
        'bg': 'a',
        'fg': 'b'
    },
    'Second': {
        'bg': 'c',
        'fg': 'd'
    }
};
```

This doesn't work:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'bg')

```
var arr = [];
arr['First']['bg'] = 'a';
arr['First']['fg'] = 'b';

arr['Second']['bg'] = 'c';
arr['Second']['fg'] = 'd';
```

Comment: You have to create `arr.First` before you can create `arr.First.bg`

Comment: that's and object of objects, not an array, an array should be like this `[{a: "hi", b: 2}, {.....}]` and if it's in JSON format you need to parse it before using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create intermediate objects before you can create the nested properties.

```
var arr = {};
arr['First'] = {};
arr['First']['bg'] = 'a';
arr['First']['fg'] = 'b';
arr['Second'] = {};
arr['Second']['bg'] = 'c';
arr['Second']['fg'] = 'd';
```

And note that you should be using `{}`, not `[]`. `{}` is an object, `[]` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```js
var arr = {};

// Create the "First" 
arr['First'] = {};
arr['First']['bg'] = 'a';
arr['First']['fg'] = 'b';

// Create the "Second"
arr['Second'] = {};
arr['Second']['bg'] = 'c';
arr['Second']['fg'] = 'd';

console.log(arr);
```